# SUMIF formula refuses to work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of values, given below, in column A of my worksheet

```
635320393516930000.00
635320394621433000.00
635320395928558000.00
635320397215862000.00
635320397973875000.00
635320398849985000.00
635320400627157000.00
635320401276114000.00
635320402391388000.00
635320403478360000.00
635320405195488000.00
635320405862506000.00
635320406509623000.00
```

However, both of these formulae return a sum of 0:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,A:A, ">=((41730*864000000000)+599266080000000000)")
=SUMIFS(A:A,A:A, "<=((41730*864000000000)+599266080000000000)")
```

Which seems to me to be incredibly weird; how does neither of these formulae catch any of the numbers in the formula's range? Surely the numbers HAVE to be greater, lesser or equal to the value I've given.

So my question is: what's wrong with these formulae!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is that you're not calculating the value of `((41730*864000000000)+599266080000000000)` but merely putting it as text. If you want it to calculate, put it outside quotes:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,A:A, ">="&((41730*864000000000)+599266080000000000))
```

Though I don't think you need `SUMIFS` for that. `SUMIF` should work:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, ">="&((41730*864000000000)+599266080000000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are writting your formula you are doing a text compare of the numbers try the following:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,A:A, ">=" & (41730*864000000000)+599266080000000000)
=SUMIFS(A:A,A:A, "<=" & (41730*864000000000)+599266080000000000)
```